# Using HTTPS with MAAS web interface login redirects to HTTP

Tags: maas

I need to use HTTPS for login into MAAS web interface.
But when I goto **https:// ip-of-maas /MAAS/**, it redirects you to **http:// ip-of-maas /MAAS/accounts/login/?next=%2FMAAS%2F** which makes HTTPS useless as password will be transported in plain text.
I also tried it by following steps given in documentation for supporting SSL which basically asks you to run this command:

```
maas-region-admin local_config_set --maas-url="https://localhost:5240/MAAS"
```

I also tried updating maas_url with https in /etc/maas/clusterd.conf but still the behavior is same.

I need to disable web access to MAAS through HTTP. So I have used apache module rewrite  for redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS which overcomes this behavior:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.10\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

This basically redirects all HTTP requests from subnet different from 10.10.0.0/16 to HTTPS.

Shouldn't MAAS automatically redirect you to HTTPS url once you land on **https:// ip-of-maas /MAAS/**. Am I missing any configuration ?

Is this a bug that I should raise on launchpad ?